# how to remove the slash in json object in android?

Tags: android, json, android-studio

i have trouble to remove the slash at particular  place in j son object.
how to remove the slash in between in  j son object. here i will mentioned my json

```
{
 "property": [
{
  "ad_detail": {
    "id": 15,
    "ad_id": "PFAS1015",
    "user_id": "1",
    "project": "chennai builders",
    "locality": "Pallikaranai",
    "city": "Chennai",
    "address": "Kamakshi colony",
    "landmark": "near mother matric school",
    "property_type": "apartment",
    "sale_type": "new",
    "description": "one of the best apartment near to pallikaranai",
    "validity_expire": "2016-11-17 12:11:14",
    "payment": "yes",
    "payment_details": "cash",
    "images": "",
    "videos": "",
    "booking_amount": "12",
    "total_cost": "20",
    "additional_cost": "02",
    "ad_status": "pending_verification",
    "ad_type": "sell",
    "ad_level": "premium",
    "num_views": "",
    "created_at": "2016-10-18 12:11:14",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-18 12:15:23"
  },
  "property_detail": {
    "id": 11,
    "user_id": "1",
    "ad_id": "PFAS1015",
    "ad_type": "sell",
    "bedrooms": "1bhk",
    "area": "1243",
    "area_unit": "sq_feet",
    "price": "",
    "negotiable": "Negotiable",
    "property_status": "readytomove",
    "property_age": "2",
    "possession_date": "2016-08-09 12:47:32",
    "furnishing": "semi_furni",
    "furnishings": "{\"wardrobe\":\"wardrobe\",\"bed\":\"bed\",\"ac\":\"ac\",\"tv\":\"tv\",\"sofa\":\"sofa\",\"fefrigerator\":\"fefrigerator\",\"dining_table\":\"dining_table\",\"washing_machine\":\"wa",
    "amenities": "{\"car_parking\":\"car_parking\",\"power_backup\":\"power_backup\",\"security\":\"security\",\"lift\":\"lift\",\"swimming_pool\":\"swimming_pool\"}",
    "preferred_tenants": "",
    "wardrobe": "3",
    "beds": "1",
    "ac": "1",
    "tv": "",
    "bathrooms": "3",
    "balconies": "4",
    "floorno": "21",
    "totalfloor": "3",
    "open_side": "1",
    "facing": "west",
    "facing_width": "100",
    "facing_width_unit": "feet",
    "additional_rooms": "{\"prayer_room\":\"prayer_room\",\"study_room\":\"study_r",
    "price_include": "{\"pic\":\"pi",
    "living_dining": "2",
    "kitchen": "4",
    "master_bedroom": "4",
    "bathroom": "3",
    "balcony": "4",
    "other_bedroom": "5",
    "overlooking": "road",
    "ownership_type": "leasehold",
    "covered": "2",
    "open": "2",
    "created_at": "2016-10-18 12:11:14",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-18 12:15:23"
  }
},
{
  "ad_detail": {
    "id": 17,
    "ad_id": "PFAS1017",
    "user_id": "1",
    "project": "checkpro",
    "locality": "Pallikaranai",
    "city": "Chennai",
    "address": "Kamakshi colony",
    "landmark": "near mother matric school",
    "property_type": "apartment",
    "sale_type": "new",
    "description": "gjnmghmjhgkhjk",
    "validity_expire": "2016-11-17 12:55:12",
    "payment": "",
    "payment_details": "",
    "images": "",
    "videos": "",
    "booking_amount": "",
    "total_cost": "20",
    "additional_cost": "",
    "ad_status": "pending_verification",
    "ad_type": "sell",
    "ad_level": "",
    "num_views": "",
    "created_at": "2016-10-18 12:55:12",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-18 12:55:12"
  },
  "property_detail": {
    "id": 13,
    "user_id": "1",
    "ad_id": "PFAS1017",
    "ad_type": "sell",
    "bedrooms": "fcdxvgdxc",
    "area": "243",
    "area_unit": "meter",
    "price": "",
    "negotiable": "",
    "property_status": "live",
    "property_age": "1",
    "possession_date": "2016-08-09 12:47:32",
    "furnishing": "furnished",
    "furnishings": "\"4\"",
    "amenities": "\"2\"",
    "preferred_tenants": "",
    "wardrobe": "3",
    "beds": "6",
    "ac": "5",
    "tv": "2",
    "bathrooms": "3",
    "balconies": "4",
    "floorno": "21",
    "totalfloor": "3",
    "open_side": "12",
    "facing": "dffgdg",
    "facing_width": "234",
    "facing_width_unit": "sq.feet",
    "additional_rooms": "\"3\"",
    "price_include": "\"fdsfdsfds",
    "living_dining": "fghh",
    "kitchen": "fdgdfgd",
    "master_bedroom": "434",
    "bathroom": "fdgdf",
    "balcony": "dfsdfds",
    "other_bedroom": "dgdfgdsfg",
    "overlooking": "\"334\"",
    "ownership_type": "dsfgds",
    "covered": "dfsdfs",
    "open": "dsfds",
    "created_at": "2016-10-18 12:55:12",
    "updated_at": "2016-10-18 12:55:12"
  }
}
],
"message": "Success",
 "code": true
}
```

Comment: Are you generating that JSON in PHP? You are probably adding "string" encoded JSON to your actual JSON. For it to work properly, you need to keep all working objects as decoded (array / object) form in PHP, then at the end encode it to a string for delivery.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do the job

```
String newJson = oldJson.replaceAll("\\\\", "");
```

Comment: i will tried the above method but after that i cant get the value , because the JSON is converted in string @J.Wallner

Comment: Then create a new JSONObject using your String, assuming it's a valid JSON String